# как в bootstrap сделать, чтоб контейнер был по центру?

Tags: bootstrap

здесь выделенные красные блоки расположены от левого края

[image: скриншот]

как отцентровать выделенные красные блоки?

```
        <div class="container-fluid" id="head-top1">            

            <div class="row"> 
            <div class=" col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 ">
                <div class="collapse  navbar-collapse" >
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
                        <li><a></a></li>
                        <li>   
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" >
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x" style="color: #C11D37"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-stack-1x " style="color: #FFCB05"></i>
                            </span>
                        </li> 
                        <li><a href="#">sales@targetspanishproperties.com</a></li>
                        <li> ... </ul> ...</div>
```

в CSS свойствах там описание свойств fa-элементов, контейнеров нет

Comment: Добавить в вопрос HTML и CSS этих блоков. Без них непонятно, что у вас происходит.

Comment: заместо container-fluid используйте родной контейнер container - он уже выравненый по центру

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у меня получилось это исправить используя тег center !!!
внутри блока div class="conteiner"
да, есть много  разных способов которые я опробовал,но конкретное решение вопроса за тегом center
потому, что свойство text-align, например, в хроме и мазиле дает разное свойство, там двигает только текст (судя по названию и описанию свойства), а там двигает весь блок!!! 
НАШЕЛ способ как заменить тег center свойствами CSS:

```
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            width: 100%;
            display: table;
        }

        .center {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center">
        <img src="images/logo.png">
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

класс `container` добавь к блоку, который надо отцентрировать.
А вообще неплохо бы увидеть код.

Comment: смотрел документацию-там ничего не нашел подходящее к решению этого вопроса...(((
просто само отображение контейнеров идет от левого края!а не по центру....

Comment: @Александр container отцентрован посредством auto margin. Решение и правда – либо поместить в контайнер, либо у container-fluid задать ширину.

Comment: <div class="container-fluid" id="head-top1" style="width:auto">

ничего не изменилось.....а ЧТО засовывать в контейнер??там и тьак этих контейнеров дай Боже...